# Change Fill Color Of Series On Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, colors

I have two types of charts that will be populated into Excel by a BI tool. I need to colour the available series in them according to some rules.

The **first chart** shows expenditure by year (year is the series), and there are varying degrees of history from a few months, up to 24 months.  This means my 24 months of data is spread over ***years*** 2015, 2016, 2017. Next year this changes to 2016, 2017, 2018 as I’m keeping a rolling 24 months.

Whatever the data set, I need the most recent year (e.g. 2017) in the bar chart data to be displayed in blue, the year before that (e.g. 2016) in orange, and then the year before that (e.g. 2015) in grey.

It is possible I won’t have 24 months (e.g. new clients). If there are only six months, the same colouring logic applies, and that most recent year would need to display in blue.

**Expenditure Chart**
[image]

The **second chart** shows series values based on performance. These series are called  ‘on time’, ‘in tolerance’ and ‘late’.

Their colours need to be: ‘on time’ = mid green, ‘in tolerance’ = light green, ‘late’ = red.

1 **or** 2 **or** all 3 of these series may be present in a given chart with no predictability. I need the VBA to determine which series are available and colour accordingly.

**Performance Chart**
[image]

I cobbled together code from other feeds, and isn’t a base to build from. I think I need to use ForEach type syntax, as I know I need to loop through each of the SeriesCollection objects.

Comment: If you added some sample data and a screenshot of a typical plot that's going to increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I have added some images showing what I need to get to, and the pivots currently being linked from.

Comment: looking at the charts, it does not look like you need VBA for this. the columns always retain the same color. just modify the style of each chart to fit the requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple little routine for your first question, recoloring the series in your chart blue, orange, and gray but reverse the default order:

```
Sub ReverseDefaultColors()
  Dim iSrs As Long, nsrs As Long

  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, "No Active Chart"
  Else
    With ActiveChart
      nsrs = .SeriesCollection.Count
      ' work backwards from last series
      For iSrs = nsrs To 1 Step -1
        Select Case nsrs - iSrs
          Case 0 ' last series
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
                msoThemeColorAccent1
          Case 1 ' next to last series
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
                msoThemeColorAccent2
          Case 2 ' etc.
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
                msoThemeColorAccent3
        End Select
      Next
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Here's another for your second question, coloring green, light green, and red based on series name (adjust RGB as required). You should note that some people (about 8% of males, less than 1% of females) may have problems distinguishing between green and red. For this reason, blue and orange are often used as a preferred color scheme.

```
Sub ColorGreenToRed()
  Dim iSrs As Long, nSrs As Long
  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, "No Active Chart"
  Else
    With ActiveChart
      nSrs = .SeriesCollection.Count
      For iSrs = 1 To nSrs
        ' only format series whose names are found
        Select Case LCase$(.SeriesCollection(iSrs).Name)
          Case "on time"
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                RGB(0, 176, 80) ' Green
          Case "in tolerance"
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                RGB(146, 208, 80) ' Light Green
          Case "late"
            .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
        End Select
      Next
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```