# Changing the color of a Bar Chart in Access using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using ACCESS 2016. I have a chart on the form of class:

```
OLE Class: Microsoft Graph Chart
Class: MSGraph.Chart.8
```

**The problem:**

I am trying to change the color of the bars individually on the chart so that if value is greater than 0, it is blue, otherwise it is red

**Why I think It is a problem:**

I went through the documentation online, and there are many responses of using VBA in Excel and Word, which use a property called `SeriesCollection` of the Graph (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575647/vba-code-to-change-fill-color-of-series-on-chart))

This does not seem to be exposed or exist anymore.

I put a break point at my object `MyGraph`. I did not see a property `"SeriesCollection"` or something similar which I could use to change the colors.

Any ideas?

Comment: SeriesCollection is in the VBA Object Browser. However, I have an old mdb where I experimented with this and just tried it. No longer works. Fails on that same property. http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=29178

Comment: I got this much to work: `Debug.Print chtObj.SeriesCollection.Count`, says I have 6 series, as expected.

Comment: Had to change my code to remove the Points property. I would swear it used to work. Edit your question to post your code if you still need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Graph object in Access 2016 is significantly different from Excel's Chart object

I was able to look at the properties in a very basic graph with one series.
I could view and change the color of a data series by using one line of code

```
Graph0.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = 1738934
```

Where (1) represents my data series 1.

I assume you need to build a list of color codes to match your desired results, but that should be easy if you can modify the chart once and then use debug.print to get the above value.

Hope that helps

[Edit] - found a blue color = 16711680

[Modified] to show how to edit individual Point colors in a series[/Modified]

> This code created a different bar chart color for each set of points
>   in my 4 bar chart example

```
Graph0.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = 39423
Graph0.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Interior.Color = 8388736
Graph0.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Interior.Color = 16711935
Graph0.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Interior.Color = 32768
```

Comment: Yes, that is the code I got to work as well. I had read that MS changed graphing in Access but didn't realize it was that much. Don't even need the MSGraph reference library to manipulate the intrinsic Access graph control. I suppose if you wanted to build a chart from scratch, that would require the library but not something I want to tackle.

Comment: Agreed - not much help for it anywhere

Comment: Thank you dbmitch, +1. It seems then that the IDE is lacking and does not show the property when I type "MyGraph. ". This changes the color for the whole histogram, but not for individuals (for example, positive is blue, negative is red". Perhaps it is not designed for that and I have to add "series collection" per point.

Comment: Okay - I see what you're looking for - see my amended answer. It's just another example of Microsoft hiding the properties from the object browser. They're still there if you Debug and use trial and error properties from other examples

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I see now that I have to pretty much hack my way through...

Comment: Good luck and happy hacking!